# Do a function in Embedly

Tags: jquery, embedly

Im using a service called Embedly [LINK](http://embed.ly/docs/tutorials/jquery) The code that triggers the service goes like this:

```
  $('div#result').embedly({
        key: ':3eccf441bf0f43acbb076da9817af27d'

    });
```

I also have a function like this:

```
function remove() {     
var seen = {};
$('.embed').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).html();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
}
```

So I want to place this function inside the embedly, I tried:

```
  $('div#result').embedly({
        key: ':3eccf441bf0f43acbb076da9817af27d',
       remove()

    });
```

But it doesnt work. I also tried:

```
  $('div#result').embedly({
        key: ':3eccf441bf0f43acbb076da9817af27d',
       success: function() {
       remove()
         }

    });
```

No luck. How do I do my function inside or right after the embedly call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a few of the [examples](https://github.com/embedly/embedly-jquery/tree/master/examples) it looks like you just need to move the function out of the option list, like this:

```
$('div#result').embedly(
    // options
    {
        key: ':3eccf441bf0f43acbb076da9817af27d'
    },
    // "success" function
    function(oembed, dict) {
        remove();
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi, this didn't work for me but based on the link you provided I found the anwser, thanks:)

Comment: This is the code Im using in case you are interested:      `$("#result").embedly({
                         key : '3eccf441bf0f43acbb076da9817af27d'
                          }).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e){
         
remove();

                         });`